# How to get 65 Heartless in the magic carpet minigame?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-2

I'm trying to complete Jiminy's journal entry where you need to kill 65 Heartless in the magic carpet minigame.

I always wind up at 62 or 63 kills. I think the missing Heartless are the Fat Bandits on the roofs. I found after some research that you're supposed to shoot other Heartless at them, but I can't seem to do that. The Heartless go crashing at random locations, but usually not at the Fat Bandit. If they do, it's not enough to kill him.

I got Fenrir, but I don't equip the Negative Combo ability, since it takes me much more time to kill the bats with it.

I'm playing the original PS2 game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the PAL version of the minigame has a bug.

At the start of the game (just after pressing the switch), you need to hold X + left stick down until 2 Heartless pop at the bottom of the tower. They won't pop anywhere else otherwise.